# Console.Read failure in C#

Tags: c#

This is a very simple bit of code.  But it is the first time I have written a console app in C#.  To put it simply, Using these two lines

```
    int iRoll;
    Console.WriteLine("Roll Dice and input number for your move");
    iRoll = Console.Read();
```

and if I enter the number 5 from the cmd window (it does not matter if it is from the number pad or the keyboard) the value for iRoll is 53.  Why is this?

Comment: `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iRoll);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) returns an `int` containing the character read from the input stream. The character `5` is encoded as 53.

If you want a string containing the line you should use `ReadLine` instead:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

You can then parse the string into an int using `int.TryParse`:

```
int iRoll;
if (int.TryParse(line, out iRoll)) {
    // use iRoll
} else {
    // handle invalid input
}
```

Comment: This is too easy a fix and a repeat.   Who seconds my motion to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you read the ASCII code of '5' char. This is 53 value .